# Creating private chat channels using socketio and laravel

Tags: php

Ive implemented this tutorial within a project of mine, and its workin all fine beetween computers in the network, now I just want to know how could I make the user able to comunicate just to 1 person(socket) and not to all.

Ive followed this guide.

https://github.com/oriceon/laravel-5-redis-and-socket.io

Answer (score 0):

For emit just to one specific socket you will need his socket.id so you can do:

```
io.sockets.connected[socketID].emit(....)
```